# Doing efficient mathematical calculations in Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, math, statistics, redis

Looking around the web for information on doing maths in Redis and don't actually find much. I'm using the Redis-RB gem in Rails, and caching lists of results:

```
e = [1738738.0, 2019461.0, 1488842.0, 2272588.0, 1506046.0, 2448701.0, 3554207.0, 1659395.0, ...]
$redis.lpush "analytics:math_test", e
```

Currently, our lists of numbers max in the thousands to tens of thousands per list per day, with number of lists likely in the thousands per day. (This is not actually that much; however, we're growing, and expect much larger sample sizes very soon.)

For each of these lists, I'd like to be able to run stats. I currently do this in-app

```
def basic_stats(arr)
  return nil if arr.nil? or arr.empty?
  min = arr.min.to_f
  max = arr.max.to_f
  total = arr.inject(:+)
  len = arr.length
  mean = total.to_f / len # to_f so we don't get an integer result
  sorted = arr.sort
  median = len % 2 == 1 ? sorted[len/2] : (sorted[len/2 - 1] + sorted[len/2]).to_f / 2
  sum = arr.inject(0){|accum, i| accum +(i-mean)**2 }
  variance = sum/(arr.length - 1).to_f
  std_dev = Math.sqrt(variance).nan? ? 0 : Math.sqrt(variance)

  {min: min, max: max, mean: mean, median: median, std_dev: std_dev, size: len}
end
```

and, while I could simply store the stats, I will often have to aggregate lists together to run stats on the aggregated list. Thus, it makes sense to store the raw numbers rather than every possible aggregated set. Because of this, I need the math to be fast, and have been exploring ways to do this. The simplest way is just doing it in-app, with 150k items in a list, this isn't actually too terrible:

```
$redis_analytics.llen "analytics:math_test", 0, -1
=> 156954
Benchmark.measure do
  basic_stats $redis_analytics.lrange("analytics:math_test", 0, -1).map(&:to_f)
end 
=>   2.650000   0.060000   2.710000 (  2.732993)
```

While I'd rather not push 3 seconds for a single calculation, given that this might be outside of my current use-case by about 10x number of samples, it's not terrible. What if we were working with a sample size of one million or so?

```
$redis_analytics.llen("analytics:math_test")
=> 1063454 
Benchmark.measure do
  basic_stats $redis_analytics.lrange("analytics:math_test", 0, -1).map(&:to_f)
end
=>  21.360000   0.340000  21.700000 ( 21.847734)
```

### Options

1. Use the SORT method on the list, then you can instantaneously get min/max/length in Redis. Unfortunately, it seems that you still have to go in-app for things like median, mean, std_dev. Unless we can calculate these in Redis.
2. Use Lua scripting to do the calculations. (I haven't learned any Lua yet, so can't say I know what this would look like. If it's likely faster, I'd like to know so I can try it.)
3. Some more efficient way to utilize Ruby, which seems a wee bit unlikely since utilizing what seems like a fairly decent stats gem has analogous results
4. Use a different database.

### Example using StatsSample gem

Using a gem seems to gain me nothing. In Python, I'd probably write a C module, not sure if many ruby stats gems are in C.

```
require 'statsample'
def basic_stats(stats)
  return nil if stats.nil? or stats.empty?
  arr = stats.to_scale

  {min: arr.min, max: arr.max, mean: arr.mean, median: arr.median, std_dev: arr.sd, size: stats.length}
end

Benchmark.measure do
  basic_stats $redis_analytics.lrange("analytics:math_test", 0, -1).map(&:to_f)
end
=>  20.860000   0.440000  21.300000 ( 21.436437)
```

### Coda

It's quite possible, of course, that such large stats calculations will simply take a long time and that I should offload them to a queue. However, given that much of this math is actually happening inside Ruby/Rails, rather than in the database, I thought I might have other options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to keep this open in case anyone has any input that could help others doing the same thing. For me, however, I've just realized that I'm spending too much time trying to force Redis to do something that SQL does quite well. If I simply dump this into Postgres, I can do really efficient aggregation AND math directly in the database. I think I was just stuck using Redis for something that, when it started, was a good idea, but scaled out to something bad.

Answer (score 3):

Lua scripting is probably the best way to solve this problem, if you can switch to Redis 2.6. Btw testing the speed should be pretty straightforward so given the small time investment needed I strongly suggest trying Lua scripting to see what is the result you get.

Another thing you could do is to use Lua to *set* data, and make sure it will also update a related Hash type per every list to directly retain the min/max/average stats, so you don't have to compute those stats every time, as they are incrementally updated. Not always possible btw, depends on your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [NArray](http://narray.rubyforge.org/). From their homepage:

> This extension library incorporates fast calculation and easy manipulation of large numerical arrays into the Ruby language.

It looks like their [array class](http://narray.rubyforge.org/SPEC.en) has most all of the functions you need built in. Cmd-F "Statistics" on that page.